# LRU page replacement using stack

Tags: c, linux, stack, lru

I am trying to write a program in Linux C using a doubly linked list that replaces pages with the LRU algorithm and using a stack for various references upon a memory of 3 and 4 frames respectively. My question is what is the best way to implement the LRU algorithm and the stack for this program?

Comment: Memory replacement is is handled automatically by the virtual memory component of the operating system, it's not something application programs can control directly.  I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this is a class assignment. I believe it is asking for a program to do something like this https://imgur.com/a/iN53Zkt

Comment: The usual algorithm is to maintain two lists "in" and "out".  Initially put all the pages (or page numbers) in the "out" list. Every time a page is referenced, search for it in the "in" list. If it's there, remove it and re-insert it at the head of the list. Otherwise find it in the "out" list and add it at the head of "in."  If the "in" list has exceeded the size of memory, the tail element is least recently used, so move it from "in" to "out."  There's no FIFO stack here.  You're constantly shuffling the lists in various ways. If you use an index, you can avoid the linear searches.

Comment: Thank you, that should cover that algorithm and the lists but I believe the assignment specifically mentions a stack. Though it's possible it was worded incorrectly or oddly

Comment: I agree with Gene that a stack seems like the wrong data structure for LRU, because it doesn't allow for reordering.